# Is it possible to create a docker image whitout OS?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, microservices

To install my microservice binaries I need a centos. And since I have 20 microservice I'm trying to find a way to optimize the images size so I'm wondering if there's a way to create a docker image without os and at the moment of deployment Docker takes the OS Layer from cache to put it in all the images.. I'm a beginner so I don't know if I'm clear in my statements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look at the **scratch** keyword ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/#create-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch)):

> You can use Docker’s reserved, minimal image, scratch, as a starting
>   point for building containers.

Also you may find useful using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/).

An example:

```
FROM scratch
ADD hello /

FROM fedora
RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
RUN yum -y install nginx
```

Comment: I've updated answer with multi-stage build example, with yum, so you'll get an idea

Comment: I'll try this and tell you if it corresponds to my need ! thank you

Comment: sorry this doesn't really answer my question... What I actually need is having an image with the yum package installed and no OS layer

Comment: I suppose that it is not possible ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need OS to run container anyway

Comment: And there is no way to remove a layer (OS layer) after an image is built ?

Comment: If you need yum, you need also python, honestly, I wouldn't be surprised if after analyzing all dependencies you will anyway end up with minimal CentOS image.